# allowing remote connection to send emails

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-18.04

i have setup my vps as  Postfix as a Send-Only SMTP Server on Ubuntu 18.04

and i want to send emails remotely not locally on server

when i send using the server locally it works

but remotely or outside server, am getting this error

```
client does not have permission to submit mail to this server. the server response was: 4.7.1 : relay access denied


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_un$
myhostname = server69092.domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, server69092.domain.com, localhost.domain.c$
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to relay emails on this server (without actually using smtp auth) you should modify this line:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

with

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 ip-of-server-which-sends-the-email
```

A real example:

Assuming you're sending emails from server with ip 1.2.3.4, then you'll have this in Postfix config:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 1.2.3.4/32
```

Do a `postfix reload` and try and see if it works. If not you could restart the postfix service and try again.

Comment: not working, i have tried it

Comment: Well it's not clear what exactly is not working...

Comment: mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 ip-of-server/32

Comment: same erroor
SMTP send error
Client does not have permission to submit mail to this server. The server response was: 4.7.1 : Relay access denied

Comment: Have you restarted postfix? The sending email address does exist on the server?